# How to synchronize two MediaPlayers or MediaElements in WPF?

Tags: wpf, video

I am trying to implement a system in WPF that plays two synchronized videos on two screens. I thought that if I bundled the two corresponding MediaTimelines into a single ParallelTimeline and control the timelines from the clock controller of the ParallelTimeline the clocks of the media timelines would be driven from the same clock and thus play in sync. Only that is not the case, there is a huge delay between both. Is there some way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, no answers still. It looks like this problem is more interesting than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

If your two MediaTimelines are in the same storyboard (and it sounds like they are), you should be able to keep the elements in sync by changing the ParallelTimeline.SlipBehavior to SlipBehavior.Slip. This behavior will "hold back" the progression of the timelines if a media element in the storyboard runs into buffering or loading delays.

You can get more details about this behavior here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304465.aspx